# Specify password hash instead of clear password in Oracle JDBC client

Tags: java, oracle, security, jdbc

I'm using Oracle JDBC driver in my Java app to reach Oracle DB. Creating the connection using code:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:port:mySID", 
"myuser", 
"mypassword");
```

requires the real password. Is there a way to specify the password hash instead such as:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:port:mySID", 
"myuser", 
"mypasswordHash");
```

Comment: can you describe further? Why you need this?

Comment: In the common approach, I either need to hardcode password (either encoded or not) or query it from the user at runtime. I just want to hardcode password hash, which is safer I believe. Querying from the user is the last option for now.

Comment: You can use Oracle Wallet (something like Java keystore) to store your passwords. And also you can use Kerberos principals for authentication, but it is non-trivial to setup.

Comment: Not sure why you think a hardcoded hash would be "safer" than a hardcoded password? If it allows someone to authenticate, it is no safer than the original password, I would have thought.

Comment: Jeffrey you're right, it was a stupid idea to use password hashes instead of passwords; that would make hashing no different than storing clear passwords in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Does the Oracle JDBC client encrypt password when you make a connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284970/does-the-oracle-jdbc-client-encrypt-password-when-you-make-a-connection) there is no need to use a hash when connecting. If you just want nobody to be able to read the password in plain text then have a look at [Encrypt Password in Configuration Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132567/encrypt-password-in-configuration-files-java).

Oracles approach closest to obfuscation seems to be wallets with "auto login": For a Java example see http://sysapp.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/how-to-oracle-wallet-with-jdbc-thin-driver-datasource-tomcat/. But this seems to require specific Oracle Admin actions: see [How to Create a Complete Wallet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asowalet.htm#i1010563) (maybe your DBA knows more about it). For other options to connect without a password in the clear see [JDBC Client-Side Security Features](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/clntsec.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I think the simplest way to go is to encrypt the password.